# Running Realm on ejected Expo projects on Android with errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I tried to run Realm on ejected Expo(both bare and managed workflow) projects on an **Android simulator**. When I tried to access realm, it showed the error as show in the picture below.

My ejected Expo project's dependencies included:
"expo": "~42.0.1",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "~0.63.4",
"realm": "^10.6.0"

The code base that I used for the test is from https://github.com/osama256/React-Native-Realm/blob/master/App.js. I tried to clone the repository and run it using react native cli and it worked.

For the ejected expo projects, the object created from realm is empty,
https://github.com/osama256/React-Native-Realm/blob/master/App.js. (line 25):

```
    const newDB = async () => {
       //empty object returned from realm 
       realm = await new Realm({ instance
         path: "myrealm",
         schema: [EmployeeSchema],
        });
       }
       newDB()
   ...
```

I highly suspect that the error is came from some configuration between realm, expo and react-native. The error occur in (line 39)

```
    realm.write(() => {
       realm.create('Employee', {
        id,
        name,
        dep
     });
  });
```

Is there anyone have similar error message and any solution to fix it? thanks for helping.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed by following the comments here: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3710#issuecomment-834056098

- downgrade the package react-native-reanimated (2.1.0 -> 1.13.3). Full steps:
  -> npm uninstall react-native-reanimated
  -> remove the node_modules folder
  -> npm ininstall
  -> npm install react-native-reanimated@1.13.3
- remove some lines of code related to react-native-reanimated on the android native module as here, https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3710#issuecomment-834427074
- remove a line from babel.config.js since react-native-reanimated need no to state there to be used(according to: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1737):

  ```
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
  ```

remark: actually there are other alternative for react-native-reanimated:
https://openbase.com/js/react-native-reanimated/alternatives?orderBy=RECOMMENDED&